# Automate user homedirectory creation Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm automating the process of creating LocalUsers on Windows systems. So far I used the Microsoft docs on [New-LocalUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) which has worked fine to create the account, this is my code so far:

```
function New-AdminUser {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [string] $UNameLocal,
        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [string] $UDescription,
        [Parameter(Position=2)]
        [System.Security.SecureString] $Password
    )

    New-LocalUser -Name $UNameLocal -Description $UDescription -Password $Password -AccountNeverExpires -Confirm
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $UNameLocal
}
```

But this command does not actually generate the homedirectory in `C:\Users\username`.
I can create this by manually logging into the created user, but I want to automate this in Powershell. I couldn't find anything in the [LocalAccounts module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/?view=powershell-5.1).

Is there any way to automate local account setup in Windows 10 using Powershell, without having to manually log in to a new account?

Comment: When a new user logs into Windows, a lot more happens beyond just creating the home user's directory. You probably won't be able to automate everything Windows does as part of its new-user logon process. Why do you _need_ the home directory to exist?

Comment: @codaamok Bit of a long story, the gist of it is that I want to use a new account on systems as a service account that will gather system information and send it to a remote server - certain software has to be installed under the new user that I want to place in it's home directory.

I want this under a new admin user to ensure an equal setup on all of my Windows systems.

Comment: If you start a process (cmd /c) as the created user, you will create his profile. Add something like this to your function:
`$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$UNameLocal", $Password)
    
Start-Process "cmd.exe" -RunAs "$UNameLocal" -Credential $Cred -ArgumentList "/C" -LoadUserProfile`

Comment: @Christophe this is the solution I was looking for, thanks. Small thing for other people finding this; the second command doesn't need `-RunAs ...` if you also provide `-Credential $Cred`.

If you post this as an answer i can accept it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start a process (cmd /c) as the created user, it will create his profile. Add this to your function:

`$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$UNameLocal", $Password)`

`Start-Process "cmd.exe" -Credential $Cred -ArgumentList "/C" -LoadUserProfile`

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code:

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$samAccountName)

$fullPath = "\\srv2012r2\Users\{0}" -f $samAccountName
$driveLetter = "Z:"

$User = Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName

if($User -ne $Null) {
    Set-ADUser $User -HomeDrive $driveLetter -HomeDirectory $fullPath -ea Stop
    $homeShare = New-Item -path $fullPath -ItemType Directory -force -ea Stop

    $acl = Get-Acl $homeShare

    $FileSystemRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Modify"
    $AccessControlType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
    $InheritanceFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
    $PropagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"InheritOnly"

    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($User.SID, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType)
    $acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)

    Set-Acl -Path $homeShare -AclObject $acl -ea Stop

    Write-Host ("HomeDirectory created at {0}" -f $fullPath)
}
```

and here is the reference:
https://activedirectoryfaq.com/2017/09/powershell-create-home-directory-grant-permissions/

Comment: This seems to be a solution for Active Directory users. As my question states I'm working with Local accounts.